# Deleting Child Records with FK Constraint SP Given TableName, ID ColumnName and ID

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is there a way to delete a record and its children in one statement? I am looking for a statement that can check FK automatically delete the parent and child records in one shot. for example if I have parent table Customers, and there are multiple child tables, such as Accounts, invoices (with a grand child table Fees) can I delete CustomerID=123 that would also delete all child and grand child records?

Ideally it would be sp where I pass tablename, and PK name and record ID ( example Customers, CustomersID, 1234

Possible [TSQL Cascade delete for child records?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732465/tsql-cascade-delete-for-child-records) can be adapted for purpose above, but not sure how.

I am using sql server 2012.

Thanks

Comment: Cascade deletes parents if a child record is delete but not all the child records for a parent record. Unfortunately there is no silver bullet for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you allowed to drop & recreate the foreign keys as per your needs? I guess you can set them with 'ON DELETE CASCADE' for both the child and the grand child table, would that do the job?

Here is an article with a sample setup - [Using DELETE CASCADE Option for Foreign Keys](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2743/using-delete-cascade-option-for-foreign-keys/)

The solution you pointed is another story I think - it handles the case of a single table where the number of levels of nesting parent-child relationship is dynamic, so that is why it uses recursive CTE on the same table.